# Dart serialization error: Invalid reference

Tags: serialization, dart

I have a wrapped [Serialization class](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/serialization/0.9.1+1/index.html#serialization/serialization.Serialization) from the [serialization package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/serialization) in my class MySerialization. In the constroctor of MySerialization, I add a bunch of rules. Consumer classes have seperate instances of the wrapper MySerialization class to (de)serialize objects.

This setup, with a seperate instance of MySerialization in consumer classes throws an error in the Reference class constructor:

```
Reference(this.parent, this.ruleNumber, this.objectNumber) {
  if (ruleNumber == null || objectNumber == null) {
    throw new SerializationException("Invalid Reference");
  }
  if (parent.rules.length < ruleNumber) {
    throw new SerializationException("Invalid Reference");  // <---- here
  }
}
```

thus spawnes error in the console

```
Breaking on exception: SerializationException(Invalid Reference)
```

This means a rule cannot be found which is referenced. The starnge thing howver is, that I have the same rules applied in all Serialization instances through the MySerialization wrapper.

I tried serializing with only one instance of MySerialization. This does **not** spawn the error. When I debug in DartEditor, I get the `<optimized out>` message in the debugger window.

I have CustomRule subclasses rules defined. The behavior does not change when I enable/disabled these CustomRules

What cuases the invalid reference, and how to solve & workaround this error?

```
Dart Editor version 1.5.3.release (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.5.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without a little more detail on your setup. However, I'm going to guess that you're using the default setup in which it will automatically generate instances of BasicRule when it encounters a class that it doesn't know about, and those are added to the list of rules. Your other instance doesn't know about those, so it fails.

You can try examining (or just printing) the list of rules in your original serialization *after* it has written out the objects and see if this is the case.

To fix this, you would need to write rules for the other objects that are being serialized and weren't in your original list. Or you could use the "selfDescribing" option, in which case it will send the rules that were used along with the original. But that won't work if you have hard-coded custom rules which it can't serialize.